# Problem while reading UCS-2 LE BOM encoded file in Apache NiFi

Tags: java, character-encoding, etl, apache-nifi

In Apache NiFi I'm trying to read a text file having encoding as `UCS-2 LE BOM` and then I'm trying to convert it to JSON. But Apache NiFi is considering it as a single line.

I tried converting to `UTF-8` using ConvertText processor but it does not support encoding `UCS-2 LE BOM`.

Does anyone know how to convert this file to `UTF-8` using Apache NiFi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UCS-2 LE BOM` is a  predecessor of `UTF-16` so try `UTF-16` in ConvertText processor.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is probably to use an `ExecuteScript` processor and rely on Groovy's String encoding.

Unfortunately, the `ConvertCharacterSet` processor is only aware of the character encodings supported by your JDK, although you may have success with `x-UTF-16LE-BOM` (see [Java 8 Character Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)).